# Presto connector for druid fails to identify tables with uppercase names

Tags: presto, druid, trino

When trying to query druid tables with uppercase names, the query fails with the error: Table 'TABLE_NAME' does not exist. A similar issue was observed in MySql connector and the attribute option "case-insensitive-name-matching" was added for MySql connector catalogue file. I have tried using the same attribute for Druid catalogue and it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you're using Facebook's version of Presto.

**TL;DR**
You need to use Trino Druid Connector to have support for `case-insensitive-name-matching`. [Trino is formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html).

**long version**
`case-insensitive-name-matching` was added first in Presto SQL (i am the author of this code, BTW) and later backported to Facebook's Presto, but apparently does not apply to their Druid connector. [Trino Druid Connector (fka Presto SQL's Druid Connector)](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/druid.html) does not have this limitation. You can use either Presto 350 (before project rename) or [Trino 351](https://trino.io/download.html) (after rename).

Comment: I tried it with both Presto 350 and Trino 351, it's still not able to recognise table names with capital letters. I have added  case-insensitive-name-matching=true in etc/catalogue/druid.proprties file (as default value is false, but seems a little counter intuitive) without any effect. Its still throwing the same table does not exist error.

Comment: This looks like a bug, and i think i know whether the fix would be. Would you mind filing a new issue https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/new?